# Hibernate JPA interceptor doesn't get call

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, interceptor

The setup I have an old project that is stuck to jdk 1.5, thus spring and hibernate versions are also the maximum possible to support this version of java. Hibernate is 3.3.2.GA and spring is 3.1.1.RELEASE. Setup is the following:

```
<persistence-unit name="myUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <mapping-file>persistence-query.xml</mapping-file>
    ...
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.myproj.common.dao.AuditInterceptor"/>         
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

application context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>                                         
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>   
<bean id="applicationContextProvder" class="com.myproj.common.utils.ApplicationContextProvider"/>   
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" >
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
 </bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<!-- Local transaction management -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>
```

and my interceptor:

```
@Component
public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 98658932451L;

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void afterTransactionBegin(Transaction tx) {
    if (user != null) {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("call ah_audit_pkg.SetAudit('test')");
        super.afterTransactionBegin(tx);
     }
 }  
}
```

I run a junit to test that interceptor is getting called and it is not. In debug mode, I am able to see this:
[image]

Any help is appreciated! Why my intercetprot is not getting called.

Edit:

I also tried the interceptor to override the afterTransactionBegin but it didn't help.

Comment: Even if the interceptor would be called it would fail. Spring isn't managing the component (hibernate is) your `@Autowired` would not work and you would run into a null pointer.

Comment: @M.Deinum All the autowired components are intitialized.

Comment: Moreover, if I Autowire the inteceptor in my junit test, it is initialized correctly by spring, meaning that spring creats that bean properly. It is just not called when it should be.

Comment: No it isn't... You will get multiple instances... The Spring configured and detected instance isn't the one that is going to be used by Hibernate. Hibernate is going to create a new instance using reflection and that will never be injected by Spring...

Comment: Ok. How do I fix this?

Comment: You will have to do the injection manually. Also you shouldn't be using interceptors any more but an EventListener in newer hibernate versions.

Comment: Do you mean I should re-create the session with a new AuditInterceptor passed as param ? There is very little chance this project will ever move to newer version of hibernate and if it does, it will have to be re-written, so I bother for now just to get the interceptor working.

Comment: Please add the spring, hibernate and hibernate entity manager versions you are using.

Comment: The spring and hibernate versions are mentioned on the top of the question. Hibernate entity manager is the same version as hibernate.

Comment: I cannot find a reference of setting the interceptor through that property in that version of hibernate only through code when opening a session. Appears to be added in later versions (the first reference I find is in the 3.5 version of the `hibernate-entitymanager` documentation).

Comment: :( What other alternatives do you think I can try?

Comment: Upgrade your versions...

Comment: not the best option for a 12 years old project. Anyway that you very much for help. Will continue trying.

Comment: Well you could probably hack your way around it with some AOP. Also if you only want to execute some SQL, then why not simply wrap the `DataSource` and execute that query on the `getConnection` call.

Comment: Thanks for ideas. Will give it a try with AOP. With the datasource connection I didn't think about it. Might try it too if  AOP doesn't work for me.

Comment: Wrapping the `DataSource` is the easiest (although you could do that with AOP as well :) ). Beauty is that it would work even without hibernate and using a plain `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: That's true. Will try it now and will update later if I get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution:
I have my entityt that extends from a superclass mapped entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyTable extends AuditInfo
```

The `AuditInfo` entity has the following mapping:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AuditInfo implements Serializable {

...

    @PrePersist
    void onCreate() throws SQLException {
        //this empty method is needed for AOP to trigger the audit information insert before entity is stored
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void onPersist() throws SQLException {
        //this empty method is needed for AOP to trigger the audit information insert before entity is updated
    }

    @PreRemove
    void onRemove() throws SQLException {
        //this empty method is needed for AOP to trigger the audit information insert before entity is removed
    }
}
```

And the Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.mypackage.entities.AuditInfo.on*(..))")
    public void setAuditHistory(JoinPoint jp){      
        final AuditInfo info = ((AuditInfo)jp.getThis());
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);
        jdbcTemplate.execute(new CallableStatementCreator() {
            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("begin ah_audit_pkg.SetAudit(?,?); end;");
                stmt.setString(1, info.getAuditUser());
                if(info.getAuditLocation() != null && info.getAuditLocation().trim().length() !=0) {
                    stmt.setString(2, info.getAuditLocation());
                } else {
                    stmt.setString(2, info.getAuditUser());
                }
                return stmt;
            }
        }, new CallableStatementCallback<Object>() {
            public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                return cs.executeUpdate();
            }
        });
    }  
}
```

It is to be noted that the Spring beans are extracted from the context and not autowired - this is because AOP is a singleton class in spring implementation, and none of the autowired beans will be ever instantiated even if they are available in the context. So I had to manually retrieve them for later usage.